# Issues on printing DataGridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, printing

I have a `DataGridView`in my asp.net project as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="No List Yet" EnableModelValidation="True" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
    .....
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="DataDetails.aspx?ID={0}"
               HeaderText="View Details" SortExpression="ID" Text="View Details" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" />
        </asp:HyperLinkField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I print this page, I get resuls as expected for other columns. But for this last column, I get results as below:

[image]

I am trying to remove the text inside the parenthesis. Why is this text visible for printing? And how can I remove it for printing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am confident asp.net does not have a `DataGridView` control. Asp.net has a `GridView` control. Granted they are basically the same “type” of control, however, you may get a better response if you tag with `GridView` as they are two different things.

Comment: Thanks,  @JohnG!